# Regex for double values with comma and dot

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

```
void RandomRegex(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");
    if (regex.IsMatch(e.Text) && !(e.Text == "," && ((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains(e.Text)))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

How can I change it that it also accepts 0,5 with a dot like this -> 0.5

EDIT: I use this Regex to avoid letters in TextBoxes like Height for example.

Comment: You can try using "-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?". It Matches the double number with dot only when it have digits after it.

Comment: Have you considered `TryParse()`'ing with the according CultureInfo instead of mucking with RegEx?

Comment: Instead of using Regex and *guessing* what the correct separators are, use `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse` with either the desired CultureInfo, or *no* CultureInfo to use the user's current culture

Comment: I don't want to use TryParse because it still allows letters in TextBoxes. I want only numbers.

Comment: double.TryParse returns false if the input contains letters. `H5.0` is no valid double value. Same for int.TryParse

Comment: How would that look like? I have one but don't know how to bind that to my xaml static double ConvertToDouble(String input)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(input, out double result))
                return result; 
            else
                return 0.0; 
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `"[0-9,\\.]+"` could work here.

```
var pattern = "[0-9,\\.]+";

foreach( var test in new [] {"0,5", "0.5", "", "abc"})
     Console.WriteLine($"{test}: {Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern)}");
```

```
0,5: True
0.5: True
: False
abc: False
```

---

As others have pointed out you could make your number parsing better.

You could:

- (probably preferred) use the user's culture; or
- make number parsing more resilient instead.

```
foreach (var test in new[] { "0.5", "0,5", "2019,11", "2,019.11", "abc" })
{

    var frenchR = decimal.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.AllowThousands|NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), out var dec );
    bool? invariantR = null;
    if( !frenchR )
        invariantR = decimal.TryParse(test,  NumberStyles.AllowThousands|NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dec );
    //var dec2 = decimal.Parse(test, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    Console.WriteLine($"{test,10} => {dec,10} (french={frenchR}, invariant={(invariantR?.ToString()??"not attempted")})");
}
```

```
       0.5 =>        0.5 (french=False, invariant=True)
       0,5 =>        0.5 (french=True, invariant=not attempted)
   2019,11 =>    2019.11 (french=True, invariant=not attempted)
  2,019.11 =>    2019.11 (french=False, invariant=True)
       abc =>          0 (french=False, invariant=False)
```

Comment: The second set of output may be showing unexpected Boolean values. Should the code within the `if( !commaCultureResult ) ...` also have `commaCultureResult = ...`? Maybe it should assign to a different VAR and then finally write one or two booleans

Comment: No need to escape the dot in the regex: `[0-9,\\.]+` -> `[0-9,.]+`. `[0-9,\\.]+` means "0123456789,\." are allowed

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you.